# How to edit CSS classes in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

We have received the HTML designs from the team and now integrating into an Sitecore 8 project (ASP.NET).

I see that images for important elements, are declared inside the css class.

For eg: There are two types of section headers in a page - long & short, and their classes are:

```
.title-long{
  background:url('/images/bg-long.jpg');
  width:700px;
  height:80px;  
}

.title-short{
  background:url('/images/bg-short.jpg');
  width:300px;
  height:50px;  
}
```

And this is how they are used.

```
<h3 class=".title-long">A very long header</h3>
<h3 class=".title-short">short header</h3>
```

If the header title is lengthy, `title-long` class is used.
[image]

The content author (CA) should be able to edit the header as well as the image.
I have no idea how to make the image (which is referred from css class), editable from experience editor.

So, I will inform the CA that this image can be edited only from the Content editor and then my code will be:

**ascx**

```
<h2 id="sectionHeader" runat="server" class="title-long">
  <sc:Text ID="txtHeader" runat="server" Field="Section Header" />      
</h2>
```

**ascx.cs**

```
//add background image to header 
sectionHeader.Style.Add("background", "url(" + MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(headerImage.MediaItem) + ") no-repeat center center");
```

Though this approach works fine, here is the concern.

Even if CA uploads a 'short Image', the class will always be `title-long`.

What is the standard way for this situation, i.e a CA should have a good editing experience, while changing an image that is inside a css class.

Comment: If you find an answer that meets your needs, please mark it as answered. I see many questions you have asked, that have several answers, but none are marked as answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create `background image` and `css class` fields on your template (or datasource template).
2. Use `Edit Frame` for both `background image` and `css class` fields.

That's it. Authors will be able to edit them directly from Experience Editor.

More info about edit frames here: [Using Sitecore EditFrame in PageEdit](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2011/11/28/using-sitecore-editframe-in-pageedit/) or here: [https://www.google.com/search?q=sitecore+edit+frame](https://www.google.com/search?q=sitecore%20edit%20frame).

Answer (score 1):

There is always a trade of as the best place for this kind of meta content. Arguably its not truly 'content' but more a configuration for how to render the component(s) and content.

Based on this another option would be to use **rendering parameters**. These give you the ability to define fields that allow the configuration of components and can be configured via the content editor or experience editor. For more info have a look at https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/sitecore-rendering-parameters-part-1--how-and-why-to-use-rendering-parameters